# how to fix error Not allowed to load local resource chrome

Tags: php, css

am working on my php project when i try to load the css file with:

```
<link href="<?php echo(ROOT.'views/frontend/assets/css/font-awesome.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

where `ROOT` is the variable that content the path of project on the local server.
in the browser i have a good path:
`<link href="C:/wamp64/www/Clearence_Form/views/frontend/assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">`

but i the consol of the browser i have the error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/wamp64/www/Clearence_Form/views/frontend/assets/css/bootstrap.css`

how can i fix this??
thanks!!

Comment: Never put the full path like `href="C:/wamp64/www/` as when you move this code. **It wont work**

Comment: `<link href="views/frontend/assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: i want to do something that is dynamic

Comment: because that line is on my `header.php` file that i will include in the `index.php` after

Comment: Then use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: PS You shoudl be using a Virtual Host and not just relying on a subdirectory of www. See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990618/2310830)

Comment: thanks i use the virtual host!!